# Dynamic CollectionView depends on TableViewCell Values in SWIFT 4.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, storyboard

just starting work with swift and I got the problem that I myself can't be solved it.

so here, I got a View that structured like this

[ViewController Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvCYC.png)

and imagine i've a json array like this:

```
{           
    "SCREENTIME": "15:00",
    "FORMAT": "2D"      
},
{
    "SCREENTIME": "17:00",
    "FORMAT": "2D"      
},
{
    "SCREENTIME": "21:00",
    "FORMAT": "2D"      
},
{
    "SCREENTIME": "12:00",
    "FORMAT": "3D"      
},
{
    "SCREENTIME": "14:00",
    "FORMAT": "3D"      
}
```

that 'FORMAT' variable will be placed in TableView while 'SCREENTIME' will be placed in CollectionView.

more likely need a result like this

[Result be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujhRy.png)

How to append the data into CollectionView dynamically by TableViewCell? been searching for many ways and many source code but most of them are static data and swift 2/3 while am using swift 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort your data.. after serialising JSON to Array

Your Array data

```
let array = [
        [
            "SCREENTIME": "15:00",
            "FORMAT": "2D"
],
         [
            "SCREENTIME": "17:00",
            "FORMAT": "2D"
],
         [
            "SCREENTIME": "21:00",
            "FORMAT": "2D"
],
         [
            "SCREENTIME": "12:00",
            "FORMAT": "3D"
],
         [
            "SCREENTIME": "14:00",
            "FORMAT": "3D"
]]
```

Sorting

```
var sortedArray : [String:[String]] = [:]
for dictionary in array {
if let key = dictionary["FORMAT"]{
    if let screenTime = dictionary["SCREENTIME"] {
        if sortedArray[key] != nil {
            sortedArray[key]?.append(screenTime)
        }else{
            sortedArray[key] = [screenTime]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Expected out put

```
print("Sorted Array = \(sortedArray)")
print("Number of TableView Cells      : \(sortedArray.count)")
for (index, key) in sortedArray.keys.enumerated() {
  print("Number of CollectionView Cells for Tableview cellIndex \(index) = \(sortedArray[key]!.count)")
}
```

> Sorted Array = ["3D": ["12:00", "14:00"], "2D": ["15:00", "17:00", "21:00"]]
>
> Number of TableView Cells      : 2
>
> Number of CollectionView Cells for Tableview cellIndex 0 = 2
>
> Number of CollectionView Cells for Tableview cellIndex 1 = 3

Appling this to your UI - Please Refer this sample code

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {

 var sortedArray : [String:[String]] = [:]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    let array = [ ["SCREENTIME": "15:00","FORMAT": "2D"],["SCREENTIME": "17:00","FORMAT": "2D"],["SCREENTIME": "21:00","FORMAT": "2D"],["SCREENTIME": "12:00","FORMAT": "3D"],["SCREENTIME": "14:00","FORMAT": "3D"]]

    for dictionary in array {
        if let key = dictionary["FORMAT"]{
            if let screenTime = dictionary["SCREENTIME"] {
                if sortedArray[key] != nil {
                    sortedArray[key]?.append(screenTime)
                }else{
                    sortedArray[key] = [screenTime]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sortedArray.count
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    let key = Array(sortedArray.keys)[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelShowtype.text = key
    cell.loadCollectionView(array: sortedArray[key]!)
    return cell
 }

}
```

Custom TableView Cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDataSource {
 @IBOutlet weak var labelShowtype: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
 var array = [String]()
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
 }
 func loadCollectionView(array:[String]) {
    self.array = array
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
 }
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.labelTime.text = self.array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
 }
}
```

Custom Collection View Cell

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var labelTime: UILabel!
}
```

Storyboard

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. sorry, this might be misunderstood. The problem is not in my data, but How to append the data into CollectionView dynamically

Comment: YES something like that, i'll try your code and UI. big thanks, mate :D

Comment: have been following your way but sadly tableview and collectionview value doesn't show up in my UI :( @Britto

Comment: What is your current problem? First you try to load table view with out including collection view, and see if it work

Comment: sorry it was fixed. but i want to ask, how can your label horizontally inside collectionviewcell? while mine always go vertically