# How to parse json Data into dynamic collection view sections and cells in swift

Tags: json, swift, sorting, dictionary, uicollectionview

This is the json response that I am getting from postman after making network request

```
[
    {
        "employeeName": "Find a Sub ",
        "startDate": "2020-02-25",
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "16:00:00"   
    },

   {
        "employeeName": "Find a Sub ",
        "startDate": "2020-02-25",
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "16:00:00"
    },

{
        "employeeName": "Find a Sub ",
        "startDate": "2020-02-25",
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "16:00:00"
    },

{
        "employeeName": "Find a Sub ",
        "startDate": "2020-02-24",
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "16:00:00"  
    },

{ 
        "employeeName": "Find a Sub ",
        "startDate": "2020-02-24",
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "16:00:00"     
    }]
```

This is my Model struct where I am parsing my json data

```
struct jobsData:Decodable
{
    let employeeName:String?
    let startTime:String?
    let endTime:String?
    var startDate:String?

    init(employeeName:String?=nil,
         startTime:String?=nil,
         endTime:String?=nil,
         startDate:String?=nil){

        self.employeeName=employeeName
        self.startTime=startTime
        self.endTime=endTime
        self.startDate=startDate
    }}
```

I am using json decoder to decode the data coming after urlSession request
now I need to manipulate the response in such a way that the number of sections of uicollectionview will be the startDate and its header text will be its text e.g, in above case there will be two sections of uicollectionview. each section's items will be the no of objects in json response that corresponds to that date like in above case there will be three items in section with date 2020-02-25 and two items in section with date 2020-02-24. the problem I am having is that I don't know the no of sections and no of items in each sections as the data is dynamic that is coming from an api. how can I manipulate the json response to append them in uicollectionview like I stated.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397623
this link was helpful but I don't know how to sort my data as in above link there was only two keys one for sorting and other for collectionview data but I have multiple keys.

Edited:
This is my collectionview data source function. How can I show the data in different sections

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)as! AvailableJobsCell
    let sTime=self.timeInAmPm(String: UserInformation[indexPath.item].startTime!)
    let eTime=self.timeInAmPm(String: UserInformation[indexPath.item].endTime!)
    cell.jobAddedTime.text="\(sTime) - \(eTime)"
    cell.jobTitle.text=UserInformation[indexPath.item].employeeName!
    cell.schoolName.text="\(UserInformation[indexPath.item].organizationName ?? "")\n\(UserInformation[indexPath.item].organizationAddress ?? "")"
    cell.jobNo.text=UserInformation[indexPath.item].confirmationNumber!
    cell.personOnHiatus.text=UserInformation[indexPath.item].positionDescription!
    cell.index=indexPath
    cell.delegate=self
        return cell
}
```

UserInformation is of type [JobsData]

Comment: I am using swift 5.2 and Xcode 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all declare the struct with uppercased name, with non-optional members and without the `init` method.

```
struct JobsData : Decodable
{
    let employeeName : String
    let startTime : String
    let endTime : String
    var startDate : String
}
```

To group the data declare a `Section` struct

```
struct Section
{
    let title : String
    let jobsData : [JobsData]
}
```

and declare the data source array

```
var sections = [Section]()
```

After decoding the array

```
let jobsDataArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([JobsData].self, from: data)
```

group it with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`, `map` it to a `Section` array and `sort` it

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: jobsDataArray, by: {$0.startDate})
self.sections = grouped.map{Section(title: $0.key, jobsData: $0.value)}
                      .sorted{$0.title < $1.title}
```

You can even sort the `JobsData` items in the sections simultaneously for example by `startTime`

```
self.sections = grouped.map{Section(title: $0.key, jobsData: $0.value.sorted{$0.startTime < $1.startTime})}
                      .sorted{$0.title < $1.title}
```

---

To display the sections implement the datasource methods

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    return sections.count
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return sections[section].jobsData.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! AvailableJobsCell
    let jobData = sections[indexPath.section].jobsData[indexPath.item]
    let sTime = self.timeInAmPm(String: jobData.startTime)
    let eTime = self.timeInAmPm(String: jobData.endTime)
    cell.jobAddedTime.text = "\(sTime) - \(eTime)"
    cell.jobTitle.text = jobData.employeeName
    cell.schoolName.text = "\(jobData.organizationName ?? "")\n\(jobData.organizationAddress ?? "")"
    cell.jobNo.text = jobData.confirmationNumber!
    cell.personOnHiatus.text = jobData.positionDescription!
    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i try to declare Section struct "Use of undeclared type 'JobsData' ". how can I resolve this

Comment: As I said please declare the struct `JobsData` with starting uppercase letter as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited my question. now how can I use the data from sections to show it in different section of uicollectionview. I have added uicollectionview datasource function above

Comment: See the update. And please conform to the naming convention. Variables, functions, properties, enum cases and  parameter labels start with a lowercase letter. Structs, classes, enums start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. Can you please recommend me websites or books on how can I improve these shortcomings like parsing json and change json according to need and also how to make datasource functions dynamic.

Comment: IMHO the best starting point is the Apple Documentation, Sample Code and the WWDC videos.